# Beginner | Hardcode an image URL path in php | Modify Rank Math Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I've asked a few questions here in the past and everyone has been very gracious about answering me. I am about as 'beginner' as it gets. Thank you in advance.

So I am using the premium version of the Rank Math SEO plugin for wordpress. Regarding the SCHEMA creation feature: The issue is that the plugin pulls the author image from the gravatar profile (and I don't use gravatar to sign into my wordpress website). I want to hardcode the image URL for the author in the Rank Math php files (I'm the only author on my website so it's okay). Website is https://mbastory [dot] builders

Here is the snippet of php that fetches the image URL

```
    private function add_image( &$entity, $author_id, $jsonld ) {
        $entity['image'] = [
            '@type'   => 'ImageObject',
            '@id'     => get_avatar_url( $author_id ), 
            'url'     => get_avatar_url( $author_id ),
            'caption' => get_the_author(),
        ];

        $jsonld->add_prop( 'language', $entity['image'] );
    }
```

And here is what I am thinking might work. I want to print the url and attach the #author at the end of it for the @id and then I want to display the image for the URL.

```
    private function add_image( &$entity, $author_id, $jsonld ) {
        $entity['image'] = [
            '@type'   => 'ImageObject',
            '@id'     => echo 'https//mbastory.builders/wp-content/uploads/Leah-Derus-Circular-Light-Grey-500px.png#author', 
            'url'     => $filepath= '\wp-content\uploads\Leah-Derus-Circular-Light-Grey-500px.png'; echo '<img src="'.$filepath.'">',
            'caption' => get_the_author(),
        ];

        $jsonld->add_prop( 'language', $entity['image'] );
    }
```

**
Does this seem right?**

No surprise (to me at least)...my code through a huge critical error...

Comment: If you got an error, please tell us the specific error message you experienced (e.g. what you saw on screen or what was in the PHP log as a more detailed exception).

Comment: Take out that `echo` in your `add_image` function as a start.

Comment: _And_ make it a proper URL. (Currently missing a `:` in `https//`.)

Comment: Maybe search in the plugin forum first ? https://support.rankmath.com/ticket/img-author-in-schema/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying plugin files (which isn't a good practice *unless* you coded the plugin yourself or you know for sure that the plugin will no longer receive any updates) you could also use the [get_avatar_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_avatar_url/) filter hook to change it from your theme's functions.php file, like so for example:

```php
function wp99835_filter_get_avatar_url( $url, $id_or_email, $args ) {
    $url = 'https//mbastory.builders/wp-content/uploads/Leah-Derus-Circular-Light-Grey-500px.png';
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'get_avatar_url', 'wp99835_filter_get_avatar_url', 10, 3 );
```

This way future RankMath updates won't undo your changes.